# How to write script that watching directory for lessc command?

Tags: shell-script

I use [lesscss](http://lesscss.org/) extensively. I want to write bash script that watching my target directory, and then when `.less` file was modified and saved, command: `lessc` should be executed automatically.

For example, I have directory, named `css`. When `css/app/main.less` was modified, command `lessc main.less > main.css` should be executed.

Comment: I am not sure is the `lesscss` implements the same as [`pyscss`](https://github.com/Kronuz/pyScss), but the latter has the option `-w` that does exactly that watching and recompiling.

Comment: @Anthon as I know, watch mode of lesscss work in client side(browser) which is not the function I am looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a great job for inotify-tools

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
  inotifywait -e modify css/app/main.less;
  lessc main.less > main.css
  sleep 1
done
```

Inotifywait creates an inotify watch on the directory css/app/main.less and waits until that file is modified. In this event, inotifywait terminates and the lessc main.less > main.css script from above will be executed.

Comment: Can I use ``*.less`` to trigger when whatever file with ``.less`` has been modified? If yes, how can I get the modified file's name?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [inoticoming](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/inoticoming) or [incron](http://packages.debian.org/source/wheezy/incron). The advantage over inotify-tools is, that it's a service and you don't need a script that is constantly running in a do-while-loop. The links I provided are Debian-specific, but you should find at least incron in most distributions!

Also have a look at this [configuration instructions](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-inotify-examples-to-replicate-directories/) for incron.